# Excel 2016: how to find all superstring matches in a column of cells from another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, string

I have two columns of strings in Excel 2016. Column A is long. Column B is short. I need to:

1. Loop over all cells in col B
2. For each cell, I need to find all cells in col A where the string from B is a substring. So if the cell from B is "foo", and row 5 of A has "fooA" and row 25 has "Bfoo" I need to find both of them, and only those
3. I need to show all matches somehow. That is, for every cell in B I need to quickly see all superstring matches from A

How can I do this?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the elements of an array or a range for a substring with `SEARCH`. Filter an array or a range with `FILTER`.

For example, searching for the text in E1 this goes in E2:

```
=FILTER($A$1:$A$6,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(E1,$A$1:$A$6))))
```

[image]

`SEARCH` returns the first position of the substring within the string. If it can't find the substring, it returns an error. So, if `SEARCH` doesn't return an error, it's found the substring. This gives us an array of `TRUE`/`FALSE` the same length as the long list in column A. This becomes the `include` parameter of the `FILTER` function.